# How do I catch the COMException thrown by disconnected StreamSocket in C++/CX?

Tags: sockets, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm writing an application that should retranslate some data received from Bluetooth LE device to all TCP clients connected to it. The platform is Windows 10. For now it is console application with C++/CX enable as Bluetooth LE API is only available from WinRT. The BLE part is ready but I cannot make proper TCP server using WinRT.

I'm creating TCP socket server using StreamSocketListener and store all StreamSocket objects in std::vector. In a loop iterate the vector and send the data to all connected clients. Everything is working fine at this point. But should one client disconnect and the server crashes as it tries to send a data to disconnected socket and throws COMException and I cannot catch it.

Visual Studio 2015 crash message: `Exception thrown at 0x752ADAE8 in SensoCLI.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x02EFE1C0.` Call stack points to `auto sent = writeTask.get();`

Below is the minimal listing of my app that corresponds to the problem:

```
#include "pch.h"
#using <platform.winmd>
#using <Windows.winmd>

using namespace std;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace concurrency;
namespace WFC = Windows::Foundation::Collections;
namespace WNS = Windows::Networking::Sockets;
namespace WSS = Windows::Storage::Streams;

bool shouldStop = false;

// TCP socket server
WNS::StreamSocketListener ^tcpListener;
vector<WNS::StreamSocket ^> *tcpClients;

void OnSocketConnectionReceived(WNS::StreamSocketListener ^aListener, WNS::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs ^args);

int main(Array<String ^> ^args)
{
    tcpClients = new vector<WNS::StreamSocket ^>();
    tcpListener = ref new WNS::StreamSocketListener();
    tcpListener->ConnectionReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<WNS::StreamSocketListener ^, WNS::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs ^>(&OnSocketConnectionReceived);
    auto listenTask = create_task(tcpListener->BindServiceNameAsync("53450"));
    listenTask.wait();

    while (!shouldStop)
    {
        if (tcpClients->size() > 0)
        {
            auto netDataStream = ref new WSS::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            auto writer = ref new WSS::DataWriter(netDataStream);
            auto reader = ref new WSS::DataReader(netDataStream->GetInputStreamAt(0));
            String^ stringToSend("Hello");
            writer->WriteUInt32(writer->MeasureString(stringToSend));
            writer->WriteString(stringToSend);
            auto aTask = create_task(writer->StoreAsync());
            unsigned int bytesStored = aTask.get();
            aTask = create_task(reader->LoadAsync(bytesStored));
            aTask.wait();
            auto netData = reader->ReadBuffer(bytesStored);

            for (auto iter = tcpClients->begin(); iter != tcpClients->end(); ++iter)
            {
                create_task((*iter)->OutputStream->WriteAsync(netData)).then([](task<unsigned int> writeTask) {
                    try
                    {
                        // Try getting an exception.
                        auto sent = writeTask.get();
                        wcout << L"Sent: " << sent << endl;
                    }
                    catch (Exception^ exception)
                    {
                        wcout << L"Send failed with error: " << exception->Message->Data() << " " << endl;
                    }
                });
            }
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}

void OnSocketConnectionReceived(WNS::StreamSocketListener ^aListener, WNS::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs ^args)
{
    auto sock = args->Socket;
    tcpClients->push_back(sock);
}
```

How do I properly catch the exception and handle disconnected StreamSocket?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br224650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I already use WinRT with C++/CX extensions. I can't handle an exception thrown by one of its component (StreamSocket).

Comment: If you are using the Windows Runtime, why aren't you initializing your threads that do, as suggested by Hans Passant?

Comment: I don't need to do RoInitialize when using WinRT-based main and C++/CX. Example: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/29/using-ccx-in-desktop-apps/